# setting environment variables in ansible permanently

Tags: deployment, server, ansible

i am using ansible to add permanent environment variables in ubuntu bashrc .
i have these settings defined in `prod_vars` file:

```
enviornment_variables:
  PRODUCTION:
    MONGO_IP: 0.0.0.0
    MONGO_PORT: 27017
    ELASTIC_IP: localhost
    ELASTIC_PORT: 9200
```

how can i export it using a `task`? i kniow about `lineinfile` module but i do not want to repeat for every env var

```
- name: set env in the bashrc files
  lineinfile: dest=/home/user/.bashrc line='export MONGO_IP=enviornment_variables[PRODUCTION][MONGO_IP]'
```

also above command gives synatx error?

Comment: Don't do it. Instead, source files from (for example) `.bashrc.d`, use a template in Ansible to create a file under `.bashrc.d`.

Comment: how can i do that? also why `.bashrc.d`  .?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `lineinfile` module, use the `blockinfile` module.
So something like this should work:

`- name: Adding to environment variables for user
    blockinfile:
        path: /home/user/.bashrc
        insertafter: EOF
        block: |
          export {{ item.key }}={{ item.val }}
        marker: "# {mark} {{ item.key }}"
    with_dict:
        "{{ enviornment_variables['PRODUCTION'] }}"`

ps: The spelling error in "environment" literally took 20+ minutes for me to identify!

Comment: Made my day with the spelling things. Also useful.